# variable name changing in whole program

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a provision in Xcode, that I can specify which variable name I want to change, and wherever that variable is used in all of the program, the old name is replaced by the new one, without affecting the program in any way. Is there a way to do it ? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use find and replace in the workspace or you can use the Find menu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes "edit all in scope" is useful when you want to replace a variable or method name within a single source file. Select the variable or method name in question and then press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and as you edit it, it will simultaneously change it everywhere appropriate for the scope of that symbol (which, for class property, ivar, or method, will be everywhere in that class).

If you need something broader than a single source file, then you may want to use “Editor” » “Refactor” » “Rename” and it will find all occurrences in multiple source files throughout the project, including, storyboards, NIBs, etc. If files need to be renamed, as part of the process (e.g. you’re renaming some class/struct that was defined in a source file of the same name). It can even find occurrences of the renamed type in comments and string literals (though by default, those won’t be changed unless you explicitly tap the <kbd>+</kbd> icon next to that occurrence):

[image]

The “Refactor” » “Rename” is not perfect, but it dramatically simplifies renaming of types, enumerations, properties, etc., throughout a project. It’s especially useful when renaming an `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` references, updating the storyboard references, too, saving you from having to go back, remove old storyboard references and hooking up the renamed ones.

Comment: Is there also a shortcut for “Editor” -> “Refactor” -> “Rename”?

Comment: @BrunoBieri - No, but just add one: “Xcode” » “Preferences” » “Key Bindings”, search for “Rename” and then add whatever key binding you want (e.g. I use option+r).

Answer (score 8):

1. right click the variable you want to rename
2. select Refactor
3. select rename

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.

1. You can use the `Find` menu for and choose the `Find and Replace in Workspace` from the menu.
   [image: Find Menu]
2. You can use the XCode sidebar shortcut
   [image: XCode Sidebar]
3. You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the variable name you want to change.
Right Click
->Refactor
->Rename
Enter the name you want to change it to.
->Press Preview

When the helper appears, make sure you are changing all the variable the correct locations and voila.

Another way is to find and replace throughout the project.